# Jquery: how clear form input pre-filled by browser?

Tags: jquery

I know that maybe I could use `autocomplete="off"`, but i would, also to learn something new, make this with Jquery.

Browser (FF in my case) auto-fill a form. So i would to reset all fields.

I'm using this code but (obviously?) it **doesn't read browser** compiling (in DOM doesn't exist that prefilled value, I think).

```
$(':input','.not-filling')
.not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
.val('')
.text('')
.removeAttr('checked')
.removeAttr('selected');
```

and the form is a simple

```
<form class="not-filling" method="post" action="new-user.php">
     <input type="text" name="username" />
</form>
```

Thank you

Comment: Surely there are many other things to learn instead of reinventing the wheel. You can simply reset the form `$('form')[0].reset()`

Comment: try inside $(document).ready(function() { });

Comment: @undefined sorry, but doesn't work. I did try inside document.ready(function) and outside.

Comment: @TamilSelvan sure, i did insert my code (and other proposed) inside document.ready ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('.not-filling').trigger('reset');`

This small code on jQuery will reset your form.

Comment: Sir, it doesn't function :(

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I got the problem, but it seems you want to change the values of the form's input fields to be empty. The problem with form.reset is that it does not empty the form but restore its initial state (probably with some default values).

If you want to completely empty your fields you have to change their attributes like this

```
$('form input').attr("value", "");
```

Be aware that changing the property of an input field (like in jquery's `val()` function) doesn't help here.